# alterative to set for object arrays in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

Hello I have set keyword used for an object in vbscript but it doesnt work with an array is their an alterative? Or do i just have to specify the arrays type specifically for set to work?
heres the line of code causing fraustration:
GenericHIDDev(i) = CreateObject("SoftHIDReceiver.HIDDevice.1")

Comment: why doesn't it work?  more code would help

Comment: Sorry set should have been used but it turns out it was a completely different error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBScript you should use [`Set Statement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4afksd44%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) when you need assign an object reference to a variable.

```vb
Dim GenericHIDDev(0)
'GenericHIDDev(0) = CreateObject("SoftHIDReceiver.HIDDevice.1") ' wrong assignment
Set GenericHIDDev(0) = CreateObject("SoftHIDReceiver.HIDDevice.1") ' correct assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont't have your object but the following works, so use array(object)

```
GenericHIDDev = array(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"))
wscript.echo GenericHIDDev(0).FileExists("c:\test.vbs")
```

Comment: Never mind it turn out to be another error and so I fixed it.